# "SyntaxError with Tailwind CSS in React app: 'font' class does not exist. How to resolve?"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm developing a React web app using Tailwind CSS, and I'm encountering a SyntaxError related to the 'font' class. The error message states that the 'font' class does not exist and suggests ensuring it is defined within a @layer directive. However, I have already defined the class within a @layer base directive in my index.css file.

I've verified that I'm using Tailwind CSS version 3.0 or later, and I have set up the tailwind.config.js file correctly. I've also defined custom font families in the config file.

Could someone help me understand why I'm still encountering this error and how I can resolve it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

tailwindcss.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      primary: "Orbitron",
      secondary: "Rajdhani",
      tertiary: "Aldrich",
    },
    container: {
      padding: {
        DEFAULT: "15px",
      },
    },
    screens: {
      sm: "640px",
      md: "768px",
      lg: "960px",
      xl: "1200px",
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#0a0a0a",
        accent: "#B809C3",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        site: "url('./assets/site-bg.jpg')",
        //   about: "url('./assets/')",
        //   Services: "url('./assets')",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

index.css

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

.btn {
  background: linear-gradient(
    92.23deg,
    #ff56f6 21.43%,
    #b936ee 50.63%,
    #3bace2 100%,
    #406aff 117.04%
  );
  box-shadow: 0px 4.42148px 107.23px rgba(255, 86, 246, 0.51);
}

.btn:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(
    92.23deg,
    #406aff 21.43%,
    #3bace2 50.63%,
    #b936ee 100%,
    #ff56f6 117.04%
  );
}

.gradient,
.active {
  background: linear-gradient(
    92.23deg,
    #406aff 21.43%,
    #3bace2 50.63%,
    #b936ee 100%,
    #ff56f6 117.04%
  );
}

.active {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

@layer base {
  body {
    @apply font-secondary text-lg leading-8 text-white;
  }
  .h2 {
    @apply font-primary text-[32px] mb-6 tracking-[10%] uppercase;
  }
  .h3 {
    @apply font-primary font-semibold text-[26px] mb-6 leading-[46px];
  }
  .btn {
    @apply rounded-full font-primary text-white font-medium;
  }
  .btn-sm {
    @apply h-[48px] px-6 text-sm;
  }
  .btn-lg {
    @apply h-[56px] px-10 text-base;
  }
  .btn-link {
    @apply text-base;
  }
  .text-gradient {
    @apply bg-gradient-to-r text-transparent bg-clip-text from-[#42A6E3] to-[#FF56F6] font bold font-primary hover:from-[#FF56F6] hover:to-[#42A6E3];
  }
  .section {
    @apply py-8 lg:py-24 lg:h-screen flex items-center;
  }
}
```

Comment: `font-bold` and `font-primary` seem to be valid here .. I guess as @Wongjn pointed, it might be due to `.text-gradient` using invalid css `font`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, `font` does not seem to be a class that Tailwind "knows" about.

I would presume the error is coming from the `.text-gradient` rule:

```css
.text-gradient {
  @apply … font bold …;
}
```

You may have meant `font-bold` like:

```css
.text-gradient {
  @apply … font-bold …;
}
```

Otherwise, you would need to ensure you define `.font` (and `.bold`) in a `base`/`components`/`utilities` `@layer` or via a Tailwind Plugin.